# Asynchronously load data in android

Tags: android

**what is meant by asynchronously loading data in activity or fragment in android?**
This is my question. I searched everywhere. I'm not getting a generalized definition for this?. I can't get the term mentioned in android developer also.
Can anyone provide me the basic explanation of this term?

Comment: might help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Asynchronous** in Android mean that you do stuff while the user can interact with the **User Interface** (UI) : you are **not blocking the UI** while you are doing long stuff. So the user can still navigate, change activities or fragment and your data is still loading.

For **data** : you load it, parse it and do whatever you want in a **NON-UI Thread** (using **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** eg) and then notify the UI, and display what you need to.

You have many possibilities to **implement** Asynchronous load in Android, and you have many different way to manage your request. I personnaly recommend using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) if you need to use a **Web API**.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you load your data in a separate thread than the UI thread. You launch your HTTP request for example in another thread and when it finished you notify the UI thread to refresh display.

Answer (score 0):

This mean to load data in separate thread rather than load the data in main thread.Loading data in main thread may cause app to block

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncTask class encapsulates the creation of a background process and the synchronization with the main thread. It also supports reporting progress of the running tasks.

To use AsyncTask you must subclass it. AsyncTask uses generics and varargs. The parameters are the following AsyncTask  .

An AsyncTask is started via the execute() method.

The execute() method calls the doInBackground() and the onPostExecute() method.

TypeOfVarArgParams is passed into the doInBackground() method as input, ProgressValue is used for progress information and ResultValue must be returned from doInBackground() method and is passed to onPostExecute() as a parameter.

The doInBackground() method contains the coding instruction which should be performed in a background thread. This method runs automatically in a separate Thread.

The onPostExecute() method synchronizes itself again with the user interface thread and allows it to be updated. This method is called by the framework once the doInBackground() method finishes.